# Sprockets asset_path error on Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, sprockets

I'm working on a Sinatra project that's using Sprockets. When I add a new stylesheet in the assets folder, I get this error:

> Error compiling CSS asset
>
> Sprockets::NotImplementedError: Custom asset_path helper is not
>   implemented
>
> Extend your environment context with a custom method.
>
> ```
> environment.context_class.class_eval do
>   def asset_path(path, options = {})
>   end
> end
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the error message's suggestion: I defined the `asset_path` method in `config.ru`:

```
environment.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    "/assets/#{path}"
  end
end
```

I'm still not sure why this is needed, but it made the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the same error in **Padrino**, I defined this method in my `app.rb` and changed `environment` to `assets`:

```
assets.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    "/assets/#{path}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Has already proposed, you need to define the method `asset_path` for your environment.

This method is used by [helpers like image_url, ...](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/context.rb#L156) commonly used in CSS files. You might want to make it a little different depending on the `options[:type]` then.

Example:

```
environment.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    if type = options[:type]
      "/assets/#{type.to_s.pluralize}/#{path}"
    else
      "/assets/#{path}"
    end
  end
end
```

Doing so mill make the `asset_url` to return `/assets/path/to/your/file` while the `image_url` helper will return `/assets/images/path/to/your/file`

Answer (score 0):

Don't we need an instance of sprockets call?
For a Rails app that I'm playing with I used this in the config.ru to get rid of the error.

```
map '/assets' do
  environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
  environment.context_class.class_eval do
    def asset_path(path, options = {})
      "app/assets/#{path}"
    end
  end

  environment.append_path 'app/assets/javascripts'
  environment.append_path 'app/assets/stylesheets'
  run environment
end
```